# Nodejs & SerialPort.list() -> how to get the variable from a promise and make it usable on the hole project

Tags: node.js

Hello to everyone reading my post, i am doing programming as a hobby and learning on my own.
Recently i've got stuck on promises on NodeJS, i am working with serial port using serialport.io.
I got this piece of code:

```
const SerialPort = require('serialport');
SerialPort.list().then(ports => {
  ports.forEach(function(port) {
    console.log(port.path);
    console.log(port.vendorId);
  });
});
```

The code above gets me a specific COM port with a specific vendorId, which it does just fine when i do console.log(port.path), here is the code:

```
const SerialPort = require('serialport');
SerialPort.list().then(ports => {
  ports.forEach(function(port) {
     if(port.vendorId=="1A86")
     {
        console.log(port.path);
     }
  });
});
```

As i read the documentation it says it uses promises, i tried to use async and await with no success to make a global variable to hold the port.path with my specific COM port.

Here is what im trying to achieve:

```
const SerialPort = require('serialport');
var COM_holder="";
SerialPort.list().then(ports => {
  ports.forEach(function(port) {
     if(port.vendorId=="1A86")
     {
        COM_holder=port.path; 
        console.log(port.path); //COM4
     }
  });
});

const portser = new SerialPort(COM_holder, { baudRate: 115200 }); // COM_holder should have the value COM4 in it.
```

I've searched every thread on here about serialport.io with no success, i hope somebody can help me :).
**Here is the official serialport.io part that talks about SerialPort.list() : https://serialport.io/docs/api-stream**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe it is a better idea to hold 'portser' as global var?

```
const SerialPort = require('serialport');

let portser;
(async () => {
  try {
    const serialList = await SerialPort.list();
    const {path} = serialList.find(port => port.vendorId === '1A86');
    portser = new SerialPort(path, {baudRate: 115200});
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
})()
```